# How to download a youtube video using Python?

Tags: python, pytube

I'm trying to download a YouTube video using it's url in python but I'm getting:

> urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden

I'm using the Python library `pytube` to download the youtube video. Here is my code:

```
#importing the module 
from pytube import YouTube 
  
my=YouTube("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R4em3LKQCAQ").streams.first()
my.download()
```

I'm getting the error like below

> raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
>
> urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden

Comment: can you open this link with browser? maybe you are in region which is forbidden by google itself.

Comment: What's your real question? How to fix the error that pytube throws? Or a more general: how to download videos from YouTube?

Answer (score 6):

**Update 2022**
I no longer Maintains `mhyt` library.

you can try youtube_dl option:

To install:

```sh
pip install youtube_dl
# or for faster download and more improvements: 
#pip install yt-dlp
```

And use:

```py
from youtube_dl import YoutubeDL
# or for yt_dlp: 
# from yt_dlp import YoutubeDL
with YoutubeDL() as ydl:
    ydl.download(["https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R4em3LKQCAQ"])
```

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**:

> I have created a library that makes it.
>
> To install:
>
> `bash $ pip install mhyt`
>
> And use it like:
>
> ```py
> from mhyt import yt_download
> yt_download("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R4em3LKQCAQ","download.mp4")
> ```

Comment: great library! but how to choose quality of videos?

Comment: use ydl `format`:`yt_download("https://...",format='bestvideo')`

Answer (score 1):

I did the below way in Windows 10 for downloading youtube videos using Python

1. Download youtube-dl using

   `pip install youtube-dl`

or

```
pip3 install youtube-dl
```

2. In Python shell import subprocess like below

   `>> import subprocess`

   `>> cmd = 'youtube-dl -o my_video '+'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jzD_yyEcp0M'`

   `>> subprocess.call(cmd, shell = True)`

Hope it will work for you also.